# AIM via Gmail chat -- is it encrypted through SSL?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, https, google-talk

When using G Chat in the Gmail interface (and using SSL/HTTPS), you have the ability to log in to AIM as well.

Is this encrypted like the email and G Chat?

Recently I've noticed there is an icon that warns me that the page "Contains unauthenticated content" which makes me wonder if the AJAX it's using is encrypted or not. The details of that message say the connection is "partially encrypted".

How do I know for sure?

Comment: Are you talking about between you and the browser, or between the Gmail chat servers and AIM chat servers?

Comment: Between my machine and the next step in line. In other words, can someone on my network see the messages (in plain text) if they sniff the traffic

Answer (score 1):

It is encrypted. If you're in the non SSL version of gmail then it would not be encrypted. This is why it's suggested you set your options to always redirect you to the SSL version of gmail.

Comment: Can you cite a source or anything?

Comment: No I don't have a source but I can walk you through a quick process to verify for yourself. Direct your browser traffic through a local proxy and check the packets after you've logged into gmail and start using AIM chat. You'll notice they are SSL encrypted.